# Get all parent branch code into child branch Gitlab

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, commit

I have Gitlab branch structure as below :

- Master

  - 8.0

    - 8_TASK001
    - 8_TASK002

-> 8_TASK001 : Very old
-> 8.0       : Latest code and fixes.

I want to get all the changes from 8.0 into 8_TASK001 without getting all the history.

After getting all the code it will develope feature into 8_TASK001 and then create  a merge request into 8.0

P.S. rebase did not work.

Comment: There are really only two options: rebase, or merge. There are several methods of merging, depending on the result you would like.

Comment: merging does not copy history, it just makes a note that it is merged. So you would see it in history of TASK001 but when you merge it back it would not be duplicated in history of 8.0

Comment: instead of "rebase did not work" you could say which issues you had with it

Answer (score 0):

Merge the parent into the child?

```
git checkout 8_TASK001
git merge --no-ff 8.0
```

If you want to keep the commits from 8_TASK001, use the non fast forward merge `--no-ff` approach. Otherise do not use `--no-ff`.

Comment: In that case it will copy all the history from 8.0 into 8_TASK001, which will make it hard for review.

Comment: @ABV But you want that history don't you?

Comment: Nope. The parent branch 8.0 has already the history, I just want the code into my feature branch (8_TASK001), so that I can do the new feature development and merge into 8.0

Comment: @ABV You might have to create a new branch from 8.0 then, and merge 8_TASK001 to it.

Comment: I am sure Git has some functionality for it.

Comment: @ABV You could try the `--no-ff` merge option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147586/discussion-between-abv-and-snoopy).

Comment: I don't know how github handles back merges to PRs, but it is possible to show them nicely (there are services which do), so I'd give it a try.